# Decoration below line

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I want to make an extension that shows error in a similar way to the [lsp_lines](https://github.com/ErichDonGubler/lsp_lines.nvim):

[image: lsp_lines]

I looked the [DecorationInstanceRenderOptions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationInstanceRenderOptions) and only found before and after options, but I think that is no option to render below. Maybe there is a way the render using the after option, but breaking the line and display the content below the original line?

Comment: you can look at the source code how they do the lsp_lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API available for that UI. The decorators won’t create the *virtual lines* you have but instead, will be presented over the next lines.

VS Code itself has https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_reference-information, which presents *kind of* the same virtual line, but above the line. Having such feature available, I suppose, is a good start.

There is also https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_errors-warnings, but it is something that only displays one open at a given time, not many like decorators.

And, there is this feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3220, which asks for custom peeks.

If none of this works for you, I suggest you to open a feature request in VS Code repo.

Hope this helps

Comment: those lines "above" are `CodeLens` items and there is an extension API for that